# Apache server time changes when restarts

Tags: apache, server-configuration

in my server i have this status for apache server

```
Current Time: Thursday, 06-Dec-2018 12:52:45 +0330
Restart Time: Wednesday, 25-Mar-2020 11:12:57 +0430
```

so whenever it restarts, the time changes to 25-Mar-2020 11:12:57
how can i fix this so whenever apache restarts the server time sets to now?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo date --set="2018-10-6 10:05:59.990"
```

read this [digitalocean artical about How To Set Up Time Synchronization](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-16-04)